# how to start broadcast with encoder with youtube api in website

Tags: youtube, broadcast

I am new to youtube api.i have tried for broadcast with youtube api but it only created stream now what is next step for broadcasting from the website directly in youtube.

Comment: means, You want to know how to use broadcast in youtube,? or you want to embed in your own website.

Comment: No i want to broadcast new event in youtube not embed the existing live streaming